# javascript: get date and time of India (Not of personal computer's date and time)

Tags: javascript, datetime

How do I get date and time of India in Javascript? 
It should not take the computer's date and time, but it should take the standard world's time zone instead, without taking the personal computer's time reference.

Comment: The only way to do this is to get data from a server somewhere, such as with AJAX.

Comment: @Brad well it could get UTC time and adjust it appropriately.

Comment: *Can you please help in giving me the javascript code* No. That's not how SO works.

Comment: @Pointy, How do you expect it to do that "without taking the personal computer's time reference"?  If you are to ignore local time (as it may not be in sync), you must get it from the server.

Comment: @Brad Apparently he wants the time of India. (wasn't immediately clear to me either)

Comment: @Chiel92, No, it's perfectly clear to me.  I'm telling you that if you want to get the time without relying on the time of the local machine, you need to get it from a server.  To do that, you can use AJAX.

Comment: @Chiel92, Your edit to the question has missed an important point... you cannot simply shift time zones, as the local time on the computer may not be in sync.

Comment: @Brad well yes, if the client computer has a bad clock there's not much to be done. But there are UTC APIs for Date objects, so if the OP is willing to trust the client clock it can be done.

Comment: @Pointy, The original question specifically said that the time was needed without relying on the local clock.

Comment: @Brad point taken, I suggested another edit which will put that back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an ajax request to the server and return the time:

html

```
<p>The time is <span id="time"></span></p>
```

JS

```
var time = document.getElementById('time');

time.innerHTML = getTime();

function getTime(){
    var xmlHttp;
    try {
        //FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (err1) {
        //IE
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch (err2) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch (eerr3) {
                //AJAX not supported, use CPU time.
                alert("AJAX not supported");
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open('HEAD',window.location.href.toString(),false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    xmlHttp.send('');
    return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
}
```

Heres a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A8vxa/

Comment: this approach is more recommended.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. Javascript knows the computers date/time, but if that doesn't correspond with the current time zone, Javascript cannot detect that.

However, there are UTC APIs for Date objects, so if the OP is willing to trust the client clock it can be done.

Comment: But it doesn't know in which timezone the computer is, unless it gets the right data from some server.

Comment: Utc plus India time zone offset

Comment: @Chiel92 he can get the UTC time from the client, and the time zone for India is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a client side language. It execute on user systems, so datetime object holds users system time. but Javascript can make HTTP calls, and only to the server.

You can make a call to [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HU5qj/):

`http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=GMT`

you would get response (open it in browser) :

```
{
  "tz": "GMT", 
  "hour": 16, 
  "datetime": "Sat, 23 Feb 2013 16:07:44 +0000", 
  "second": 44, 
  "error": false, 
  "minute": 7
}
```

which is GMT time. but as it is calling some server, so your code depends on that server functionality you can make your server and handle the request accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 5 and a half hours to the UTC time for recent and future times-
India has no DST and only one time zone,at present.

Assuming you can get UTC from the client:

```
function IndiaTime(D){
    D= D || new Date();
    D.setUTCMinutes(D.getUTCMinutes()+330);

    var A= [D.getUTCHours(), D.getUTCMinutes(), D.getUTCSeconds()];
    if(A[1]<10) A[1]= '0'+A[1];
    if(A[2]<10) A[2]= '0'+A[2];
    return A.join(':');
}

alert(IndiaTime())
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function on php

```
public function ajax_getDate()
{
    ini_set("date.timezone", "Asia/Kolkata");
    echo json_encode(date('F d, Y h:i:s A')); 

    //you can use any date format you want check http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
}
```

Then use ajax to retrieve data ..

```
$.ajax({
    url : url + "ajax_getDate",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
        {
          date = data;
          // do something
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing using Node and NPM you can use this package: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ez-local-time
It incorporates all world time zones, so you can always programatically get the date and time in India.